# Help understanding limit with subtraction

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

I've been thinking about this for a while and I'm 90% sure I'm not understanding this limit right, and I'd appreciate some feedback.

I have something that looks like

$$f(x) = g(x) - h(x)$$

$f(x)$, $g(x)$, and $h(x)$ are all just functions with the following properties.
$g(x) > h(x)$ so that $f(x) > 0$.
$h(x) > x$.

I want to find $$\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = \lim_{x \to \infty} g(x) - \lim_{x \to \infty} h(x)$$.

If I can show that $\lim_{x \to \infty} g(x) \to \infty$, and $\lim_{x \to \infty} h(x) \to \infty$, then this isn't terribly helpful.

This is the idea I had. Because I know that $h(x) > x$, then I can say

$$h(x) = (1+a)x$$

where $a$ is some positive number. And because I know that $g(x) > h(x)$, then I can say

$$g(x) = (1+a+b)x$$

where again, $b$ is some positive number.

Then if I put this all together, I get

$$f(x) = (1+a+b)x - (1+a)x = bx$$

And if I now take the limit, I get

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = \lim_{x \to \infty} bx \to \infty$$.

So that's an answer, but the issue is that even though I know $h(x) > x$, I could just as easily say

$$h(x) = x + a$$

and because $g(x) > h(x)$,

$$g(x) = x + a + b$$

and by this, we get

$$f(x) = x + a + b - x - a = b$$

Applying the limit here gives us

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = \lim_{x \to \infty}b = b$$

Which of these would be correct? Is there a way to tell or do I need more information at this point? Is there a different way to pursue these limits?

Thanks all!

Comment: Just from $h(x)>x$ you cannot conclude much, certainly not that for some $a$ you have $g(x)=(1+a)x.$

Comment: If the only think you have is $g(x) > h(x) > x$ then the only thing you have is $f(x) > 0$ and that's not enough to figure out the limit at all and you shouldn't ever have assumed we could.  Ex: if $h(x)= x + \frac 1x$ and $g(x) = x+ \frac 2x$ then all your conditions are met and $f(x) =\frac 1x$ and lim = 0.  But if $h(x)=2x$ and $g(x) = 3x$ then $f(x)=x$ and $\lim = \infty$ and if $h(x) = x + 2$ and $g(x) = x+7$ then $\lim f(x) = 5$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are both equally wrong and need the same correction: $a$ and $b$ aren't necessarily constants

It is true that if $g(x)>h(x)>x$, then $h(x)=(1+a(x))x$ and $g(x)=(1+a(x)+b(x))x$ for strictly positive functions $a,b:\Bbb R^+\to\Bbb R^+$ (and the same can be said for the $h(x)=a(x)+x$, $g(x)=a(x)+b(x)+x$ case). However, this isn't really something that will help you with the general theory.

It could help in particular cases, depending on exactly what $g$ and $h$ are. But in such cases, I don't think you would think about it this abstractly. You wouldn't assign some $a$ and $b$ functions and use this result. You would just carry out the subtraction directly.

Comment: This is the clarification I was after, and it's very easy to understand, thanks so much Arthur!

Comment: Just a quick other question, if I have a function I'm trying to find the limit of, say $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)$, and I know that $f(x) > g(x)$, and I know that $\lim_{x \to \infty} g(x) \to \infty$, then does that mean that $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) \to \infty$ too?

Comment: @TinyTim Yes, that's a common way of solving limits. If you're used to using the definition of limits in proofs, this one is on the easier side.

Comment: Thanks, I think that just about helps me solve a limit I've been stuck on!